# MySQL Cumulative Totals For Each Day of the Month

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this SQL running total. I've tried some of the suggestions but haven't got it to work 100% and my totals are not in order.

The query shows number of stones and number of carats produced each day, first for stones over 5 carats, then for stones under 5 carats, so after first column which is the date, those 4 columns appear.

Then the next two columns simply add the stones together and the carats together for daily totals.

After that I would like to add two columns which create running totals of stones and carats.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
select 
  `dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date` AS `Full_Date`,
  if(isnull(`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`StonesO5`),
    0,`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`StonesO5`) AS `StonesO5`,
  if(isnull(`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`CaratsO5`),
    0,format(`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`CaratsO5`,3)) AS `CaratsO5`,
  if(isnull(`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`StonesU5`),
    0,`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`StonesU5`) AS `StonesU5`,
  if(isnull(`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`CaratsU5`),
    0,format(`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`CaratsU5`,3)) AS `CaratsU5`,

  (if(isnull(`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`StonesO5`),
     0,`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`StonesO5`) +   if(isnull(`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`StonesU5`),
     0,`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`StonesU5`)) AS `Stones`,

  format((if(isnull(`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`CaratsO5`),
    0,`qry_Register_Over5ct`.`CaratsO5`) +    if(isnull(`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`CaratsU5`),
    0,`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`CaratsU5`)),3) AS `Carats`,

  date_format(`dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date`,'%Y-%m') AS `Date_Filter` 

from 
  (
   (`dbo_List_Dates` 
     left join `qry_Register_Over5ct`
     on((`dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date`=qry_Register_Over5ct`.`Shift_Date`))
    )
   left join `qry_Register_Under5ct` 
   on((`dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date`=`qry_Register_Under5ct`.`Shift_Date`))
  ) 
where 
  (date_format(`dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date`,'%Y-%m') = date_format(now(),'%Y-%m')) 
order by 
  `dbo_List_Dates`.`Full_Date`
limit 0,31
```

Comment: see [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464)

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Are `qry_Register_Over5ct` and `qry_Register_Under5ct` views? I would guess that this is already inefficient becuse you are scanning the same tables (s) twice just to determine stone size.

Comment: Also. Check your use of ISNULL() which in MySQL only takes one parameter e.g. https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/isnull.php

Comment: The view generates the table as it should with all days on the current month in order and all columns producing results as needed. The use of IsNull is nested in an If statement, so that is also working correctly. With it, NULL values are placed in empty cells and then the maths doesn't work.

qry_Register_Over5ct and qry_Register_Under5ct are views. I am not sure how to build a view using the same source column twice, but each with different filters to produce this result, so I've built those 2 views and combined. 

Right now I only need the running totals on Stones and Carats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running totals in mysql require the use of variables. 
For example given

```
create table register (id int, dt date, carats int);
insert into register values
(1,'2016-11-01',10),(2,'2016-11-01',10),(3,'2016-11-01',1),
(4,'2016-11-02',1),
(5,'2016-11-03',10),
(6,'2016-11-05',10),(7,'2016-11-05',1);
```

and a dates table like this

```
+------------+
| dte        |
+------------+
| 2016-11-01 |
| 2016-11-02 |
| 2016-11-03 |
| 2016-11-04 |
| 2016-11-05 |
+------------+

select  s.* ,@RunningTotal:=@RunningTotal + s.LT5_GE5 RunningTotal
from
(
select d.dte,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) GE5,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats  <  5 then 1 else 0 end) LT5,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) +
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats  <  5 then 1 else 0 end) LT5_GE5
from  dates d
left join register r on r.dt = d.dte 
where  dte between  '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-05'
group by dte
) s ,(select @RunningTotal:=0) rt
```

Results

```
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
| dte        | GE5  | LT5  | LT5_GE5 | RunningTotal |
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
| 2016-11-01 |    2 |    1 |       3 |            3 |
| 2016-11-02 |    0 |    1 |       1 |            4 |
| 2016-11-03 |    1 |    0 |       1 |            5 |
| 2016-11-04 |    0 |    0 |       0 |            5 |
| 2016-11-05 |    1 |    1 |       2 |            7 |
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
```

And if you want column totals you could include a rollup in the group by

```
select  s.* ,
            cast(if(dte is null,@RunningTotal,@RunningTotal:=@RunningTotal + s.LT5_GE5) as int) RunningTotal
from
(
select d.dte,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) GE5,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats  <  5 then 1 else 0 end) LT5,
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) +
        sum(case when r.dt is not null and r.carats  <  5 then 1 else 0 end) LT5_GE5
from  dates d
left join register r on r.dt = d.dte 
where  dte between  '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-05'
group by dte with rollup
) s ,(select @RunningTotal:=0) rt
```

Result

```
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
| dte        | GE5  | LT5  | LT5_GE5 | RunningTotal |
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
| 2016-11-01 |    2 |    1 |       3 |            3 |
| 2016-11-02 |    0 |    1 |       1 |            4 |
| 2016-11-03 |    1 |    0 |       1 |            5 |
| 2016-11-04 |    0 |    0 |       0 |            5 |
| 2016-11-05 |    1 |    1 |       2 |            7 |
| NULL       |    4 |    3 |       7 |            7 |
+------------+------+------+---------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```